# Why mongo does not return all the fields?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, robo3t

I have a collection with location and name as fields.

i created index for the name with the mongoose like below,

```
eventSchema.index({name: 'text'});
```

When i run this on robomongo , it returns all the 12 fields,

```
db.getCollection('_event').find({"location.country":"United States"})
```

but when i run this on robomongo, it returns the values only with two fields , id and location,

```
db.getCollection('_event').find({$text: {$search: "2017 Honda"}},{"location.country":"United States"})
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because you have misplaced your other query expression, you specified it as a projection hence you are getting the projection with two fields:

```
db.getCollection('_event').find(
    {$text: {$search: "2017 Honda"}}, // <-- query part
    {"location.country":"United States"}  // <-- projection part
)
```

You need to move it into the the query object as:

```
db.getCollection("_event").find(
    {
        "$text": { "$search": "2017 Honda" }, 
        "location.country": "United States"
    }  
)
```

which is an implicit **[`$and`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/and/)** expression, and can also be explicitly specified as

```
db.getCollection("_event").find(
    {
        "$and": [
            { "$text": { "$search": "2017 Honda" } }, 
            { "location.country": "United States" } 
        ]
    }           
)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
db.getCollection('_event').find({
    $text: {$search: "2017 Honda"},
    "location.country":"United States"
},
{
    "location":1,
    "_id":0 // -- here we specify required fields. 1 is showing, 0 is not showing
});
```